# mdadm raid6 failed to start I/O error state active,FAILED,not started

Tags: raid

I'm trying to get a raid6 array to run, but it will not start.

Brief array history: This array was initially built with 6 disks (8TB each).

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=6 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1
```

1 disk was added to grow the array

`mdadm -v --grow --raid-devices=7 /dev/md1`

then the partition was resized in gparted.

2 further disks were added to grow the array but partition has not be re-sized again. The array had been starting automatically on boot-up, but now will not start.

```
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md1: Input/output error
```

Here are some other relevant outputs:

```
s:~$ mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Aug 25 16:25:06 2021
        Raid Level : raid6
     Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
      Raid Devices : 9
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Wed Oct  6 16:45:06 2021
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : Octavius:1  (local to host Octavius)
              UUID : 80bd1af7:20800c35:be64a577:8b62e937
            Events : 198308

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
       -       0        0        5      removed
       -       0        0        6      removed
       -       0        0        7      removed
       -       0        0        8      removed

       -       8      177        5      sync   /dev/sdl1
       -       8      161        4      sync   /dev/sdk1
       -       8      145        3      sync   /dev/sdj1
       -       8      129        2      sync   /dev/sdi1
       -       8       97        1      sync   /dev/sdg1
       -       8       49        7      sync   /dev/sdd1
       -       8       33        0      sync   /dev/sdc1
       -       8       17        6      sync   /dev/sdb1
```

/dev/sda1 should be a member of this array but is missing. I don't know why there are all the removed devices.

```
s:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 80bd1af7:20800c35:be64a577:8b62e937
           Name : Octavius:1  (local to host Octavius)
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 25 16:25:06 2021
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 9

 Avail Dev Size : 15627798528 (7451.92 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 54697251840 (52163.36 GiB 56009.99 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627786240 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 251904 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=251824 sectors, after=12288 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 9bddd5dd:790156b1:7b8e38d3:37558974

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Oct  6 16:45:06 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 40 sectors
       Checksum : b23ecdf9 - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AAAAAAAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

```
s:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 80bd1af7:20800c35:be64a577:8b62e937
           Name : Octavius:1  (local to host Octavius)
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 25 16:25:06 2021
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 9

 Avail Dev Size : 15627798528 (7451.92 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 54697251840 (52163.36 GiB 56009.99 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627786240 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 251904 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=251824 sectors, after=12288 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : ffa868e4:ee48f113:bd015c5c:7f92f378

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Oct  6 16:45:06 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 40 sectors
       Checksum : a8fd97fc - correct
         Events : 198308

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

The output from all other devices in the array is the same as for /dev/sdb1.

Any help or suggestions would be great and i can provide any other outputs that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I worked out what was wrong, though i'm not sure how it happened.

I missed the fact that all dives were marked as spare:

```
:~$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md1
:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : inactive sdi1[2](S) sda1[9](S) sdc1[0](S) sdl1[5](S) sdb1[6](S) sdk1[4](S) sdj1[3](S) sdg1[1](S) sdd1[8](S)
      70325093376 blocks super 1.2
```

So i figured i'd bite the bullet (small risk of losing a small amount of non backed-up data), stop the array, then force assemly. The array is now re-building and is the data seems to be fine.

```
:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdd1 --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot -1.
mdadm: /dev/sdi1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdl1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 6.
mdadm: /dev/sdk1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdj1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 7.
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md1 as 'clean'
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1 to /dev/md1 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdi1 to /dev/md1 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sdj1 to /dev/md1 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdk1 to /dev/md1 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/sdl1 to /dev/md1 as 5
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md1 as 6
mdadm: added /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md1 as 7
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 8 of /dev/md1
mdadm: added /dev/sda1 to /dev/md1 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md1 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 8 drives (out of 9) and 1 spare.
```

```
:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid6 sdc1[0] sda1[9] sdd1[8] sdb1[6] sdl1[5] sdk1[4] sdj1[3] sdi1[2] sdg1[1]
      54697251840 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/8] [UUUUUUUU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (1019952/7813893120) finish=1276.6min speed=101997K/sec
      bitmap: 10/59 pages [40KB], 65536KB chunk
```

I had seen this as a suggestion to fix other similar issues, however the status of my array (active, FAILED, not started) was different to all examples i could find and i was not comfortable with the force option initially.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future...